# Search multiple strings in multiple files

Tags: python, bash, sed

I have a file `messages.txt` with 100 or so lines, and I want to search inside all files of a given directory for occurrences of any of the lines in `messages.txt`. The search must be recursive.

It would also be nice if the search could be matched against a regex. It turns out that each line of the `messages.txt` is of the form `foo=bar`, and I'm only interested in the `foo`s, so I need to ignore the `=bar` for every line. (It would be easy to overcome this by preparing a new `messages.txt`, but it would be nice to know if there's a feature that does that already).

My choices here are `Python` (because I like it) and `bash scripting` (because I'm trying to learn it). I could easily come up with a `Python` script, so if you give a solution in `Python` it would be appreciated if it's in a Pythonic way. However, my preference is for `bash` - I was hoping a mixture of `sed`, `grep`, `find` and `cat` (not necessarily all of the them) might do the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use fgrep:

```
fgrep -rlf messages.txt dir
```

Or grep -f

```
grep -Frlf messages.txt dir
```

If you want to search for regex, don't use -F:

```
grep -rlf messages.txt dir
```

Update: If your lines messages.txt contain patterns like foo=bar, you can use cut with process substitution and cut in bash:

```
grep -rlf <(cut -d = -f 2- messages.txt) dir
```

Comment: `grep -rlf <(cut -d = -f 2- messages.txt) dir` did what I needed, thanks! It was much simpler than I'd expected

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -r -f message.txt *
```

should do the trick

Comment: Why? Provide some insight.

Comment: well, if you ignore the `foo=bar` part this works.